# Webview cookies not updating

Tags: android, webview

Android Webview, is loaded with a API, to start with, server, sends a unauthenticated temp "FP"(cookie name) cookie as response, in a subsequent calls the server sends, a authenticated new value for this "FP" cookie, the issues is that this new authenticated cookies never gets updated in android, it works fine on iOS platform and also works fine on desktop.

I am printing cookies each time a new URL is loaded:

```
 override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                val cookies3 = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
                Log.d("Cookie", cookies3)
            }
```

But I don't see any the new updated cookie.

Also here are my Webview settings:

```
ssoWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
```

The issues is that this new authenticated cookies never gets updated in android, it works fine on iOS platform and also works fine on desktop.